# Why can a struct implicitly convert to match a function's parameter type, but not if it's an assignment operator with the default one deleted?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

example:

```
struct c{
    void operator=(bool){}
    operator bool(){
        return false;
    }
    c&operator=(const c&)=delete;
};

void f(bool){}

int main(){
    c a,b;
    f(b); //works fine
    a=b;  //g++ -std=c++17 says: error: use of deleted function ‘c& c::operator=(const c&)’
}
```

Why does the `f(b)` call convert `b` to `bool` to match `f`'s type but `a=b` insists on not converting?

Comment: Because `c&operator=(const c&)=delete;` tells the compiler that `a=b;` cannot be done.

Comment: The fact that it can convert to the function's parameter type isn't relevant. That doesn't use the assignment operator in any way.

Comment: @chris the point is to compare that in one situation the conversion happens but in a different one it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overload resolution works by finding the best match, and then checking the accessibility of the function.  If you cannot access that function, because its protected/private or deleted, then you get an error.  With

```
f(b);
```

the only valid option is `operator bool()` so the code works.  With

```
a=b
```

The compiler finds

```
c&operator=(const c&)
// and the chain
operator bool() -> void operator=(bool)
```

The first is a better match, so it is the overload that is used, and since it is marked as `delete`, you get a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do something to "really delete" `c&operator=(const c&)` so that the compiler doesn't find it as a match?

Comment: @acupoftea Not really.  What exactly are you trying to achieve? We might be able to help you find a different/better way.

Comment: I want `a=b` to pass `b` through the conversion to `bool` and use `void operator=(bool)`. I guess I can change `c&operator=(const c&)` to do that, though it feels to me like a flaw in the language if I have to.

Comment: @acupoftea Why do you consider that a flaw?  That's an aspect of encapsulation.  You don't want, or shouldn't need, the user to know that process exists, so you overload the operator to do the behavior you want.  Then the end user just does the normal thing, but the class gives the correct output.

Comment: @acupoftea Is there a problem with using `a = bool(b);`? This would make explicit what you want the compiler to do.

Comment: @NathanOliver because if I could "really delete" the method it would feel more natural and more consistent with how I don't have to declare a `f(c)` to call `f(b)`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm indeed in this case it is a problem because `c` is a "reference to bit" class (like `vector<bool>`) has, so it would be annoying for users to manually convert.